# ms-access update with integer value causes arithmetic overflow Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: ms-access

In Access I can open the table and change the value of CRStatus with any Integer number.
But when doing that with this query:

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW dbo_V_Rechn_Header SET dbo_V_Rechn_Header.CRStatus = 2
WHERE (((dbo_V_Rechn_Header.Re_Empfaenger)=105) AND ((dbo_V_Rechn_Header.CRStatus)<>2));
```

I am getting the mentioned error. I also tried  this

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW dbo_V_Rechn_Header SET dbo_V_Rechn_Header.CRStatus = CInt(2)
WHERE (((dbo_V_Rechn_Header.Re_Empfaenger)=105) AND ((dbo_V_Rechn_Header.CRStatus)<>2));
```

but this has the same error. Even if I use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW dbo_V_Rechn_Header.Re_Empfaenger, dbo_V_Rechn_Header.CRStatus
FROM dbo_V_Rechn_Header
WHERE (((dbo_V_Rechn_Header.Re_Empfaenger)=105));
```

I can not type the '2' in manually. Only if I open the table direct, I can change the value.

Any idea why this happens?
Thanks
Max

Comment: Why are you using DISTINCTROW?

Comment: What data type is `CRStatus`?

Comment: @Gustav: datatyp int

Comment: Are you updating data in Access db or a SQLServer backend? Add appropriate tag.

Comment: Ms access is the frontend, ms-sql the backend